# How do I turn a LED on and off based on input from a PIR motion sensor?

Tags: matlab, arduino

I am trying to turn a LED on and off using an Arduino Uno. I'm using a PIR motion sensor as the input. I want the LED to turn off when the PIR sensor is not detecting anything. However, once it reads a value from pin 12 it just stays on even if the PIR sensor is not detecting anything.

My code:

```
value=readDigitalPin(a,'D12')

while value==1
      writePWMVoltage (a, 'D6', 3)
end

while value==0
      writePWMVoltage (a, 'D6', 0)
end
```

Comment: that's because you're not changing `value` inside any of the loops. Hence those loops run for infinite iterations

Comment: I edited your post to improve the grammar, format the code, and make the title a little more descriptive. You can format code by surrounding it with three consecutive backticks (`\`\`\``) before and after the block of code or by indenting with four spaces using the `{}` button.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
value=readDigitalPin(a,'D12') {
if (value==1)
      writePWMVoltage (a, 'D6', 3)
}
else {
      writePWMVoltage (a, 'D6', 0)
}
end
```

This assumes that the only possible return values of readDigitalPin are 0 and 1. If not then replace the

```
else {
```

with

```
else if(value==0) {
```

Other return values will then be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried attaching a pull down resistor to the output of your PIR sensor?
I remember running a simulation using a PIR sensor and an Arduino. I had to add a pull down resistor to the output pin to ensure that the pin stayed low when it was not detecting any motion.

After adding the pull down resistor run your original code again.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a MATLAB tag and some of the syntax, I am assuming you are using the MATLAB Support package for Arduino. If you are, try the following:

```
while true 
    value=readDigitalPin(a,'D12');
    if value==1
       writePWMVoltage (a, 'D6', 3)
    else
       writePWMVoltage (a, 'D6', 0)
    end
end
```

Note that this code is going to run on an infinite loop as well, feel free to use a digital pin and a push button to break the loop.